# Smarty: Syntax of custom functions in if statements

Tags: php, smarty

i have a smarty custom function which I have to call like this

`[{ oxcontent ident="oxhomepagefootertextblock" }]`

Now I have to check if the function returns a true or a value. I'm trying to use an if condition like this:

```
[{if oxcontent ident="oxhomepagefootertextblock"}]
    I'm true
[{/if}]
```

Although there's an similiar example here (http://forum.oxid-esales.com/showthread.php?t=782#post4754) smarty stops the execution.

Can somebody tell me what the right syntax is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried assigning the result of `oxcontent ident="oxhomepagefootertextblock"` to a variable within smarty then doing `{if myvar}{/if}`

Comment: I'll add it as an answer for people looking for this in the future.

Comment: @user1731323 you can select his answer

Comment: How is the syntax for assigning a function result to a var?

Answer (score 1):

My answer come maybe a bit to later but another solution is to use {capture} function like:

```
{capture name="oxcontentValue"}{oxcontent ident="oxhomepagefootertextblock"}{/capture}

{if $smarty.capture.oxcontentValue == true}
    {* do something *}
{else}
    {* do something else *}
{/if}
```

Reference:
http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.capture.tpl

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to assign the result of `oxcontent ident="oxhomepagefootertextblock"` to a variable in smarty ([reference](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl)). You should then be able to check it using `{if myvar}{/if}`.

Comment: Am I missing something. I have a function `functionName` but when I try `{assign "localBldg" functionName}` I don't get the result of the function I get the name of the function.